# How to use data annotations for multi Select Tag Helper to restrict the number of selected values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, data-annotations, tag-helpers

In ASP.NET MVC Core you can use, say, "Required" `data annotation` for `select tag helper` as follows.

**ViewModel**:

```
public class CitiesViewModel
{
   //Other Properties here ...
   ...
   [Required]
   [Display(Name = "City")]
   public string SelectedCity { set; get; }
   public SelectList Cities { set; get; }

}
```

**Question**: As we know we can make a `Select tag helper` a `multi` select dropdown if change the above selectedCity property to an array of string[] type. In the example below, **using data annotations**, how can we achieve the same if we require the user in the `View` below to select at most three cities?

```
public class CitiesViewModel
{
   //Other Properties here ...
   ...
   [Required]
   [Display(Name = "City")]
   public string[] SelectedCities { set; get; }
   public SelectList Cities { set; get; }
}
```

**View**:

```
@model myProj.ViewModels.CitiesViewModel
...some html here...

<select asp-for="SelectedCities" asp-items="Model.Cities"</select>

...some html here...
```

Comment: You would need to create you own validation attribute (and have it implement `IClientValidatable` is you want client side validation)

Comment: If you don't need client side validation, then yo can use `[MaxLength(3)]`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Your `if you don't need client side validation..` statement led me to believe client side validation is a preferred option here. So, I used jquery and it's worked. But I was just curious on how to use data annotation in this case. I assume, [MaxLength(3)] in my multi select example means the max length of the array of selected items. I should try that just for the data annotation case.

Comment: Actually `[MaxLength]` attribute is not supported for client side validation (introduced in MVC-5.1) so you will get both client and server side validation using `[MaxLength(3, ErrorMessage = "..")]`

Answer (score 0):

Implement **IValidatableObject** in your CitiesViewModel and inspect `ModelState.IsValid` in your controller method.

```
public class CitiesViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
   //Other Properties here ...
   ...
   [Required]
   [Display(Name = "City")]
   public string[] SelectedCities { set; get; }
   public SelectList Cities { set; get; }

   public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
   {
       if (SelectedCities?.Length > 3)
       {
           ValidationResult("Select up to 3 cities", new [] { nameof(SelectedCities) });
       }
   }
}
```